# write files and maintain folder structure

Tags: python

I'm working on a script that will read files from one location, manipulate the data, and then write the output to a different location. At the command line the user will use a -p to specify a top-level folder and then the script will recurse through there and find all the files. I'm doing this using glob right now and the reading of the file is fine.

But I also want the user to specify an output folder to write the files into and I want to maintain the folder structure of the input path.

```
for eachFile in glob(args.path + "/*/*.json"): <- this seems dangerous. Better way?
  # do something to the json file

  # output the modified data to its new home
  #outfile = os.path.join(args.output, os.path.dirname(eachFile), eachFile) <- doesn't work
  outfile = os.path.join(args.putout, os.path.dirname(eachFile)[1:], eachFile)
```

That last line is the best I've done but it has the problem of assuming this is being run on a posix machine when it strips off the `"/"` at the front of the directory. Also, let's say I pass in an input path of `~/Documents/2014` and an output of `/tmp`. The files will be written to `/tmp/Users/myusername/Documents/2014/blah/whatever.json`.

This seems like a fairly common use case so I'm surprised that I haven't found someone else that needed to do this or a simple module that does it easily. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you attempting to walk a directory structure, process files that match some pattern (*.json), and write these files and their parent directories, up to the specified top-level folder to some target directory?

Comment: correct. Once I have the right destination path I think I would use os.makedirs to create the folder and subfolders.

Comment: It would be helpful if whomever downvoted my question could have at least put in a comment to explain why it was downvoted. I think this is a legit question with evidence that I've tried something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a script that does close to what you need.  The key thing here, is instead of glob, you needed os.walk because you want to drill down through the directory structure.  You'll need to add sanity checks, but it's a good start.

```
# Recurse and process files.
import os
import sys
from fnmatch import fnmatch
import shutil


def process(src_dir, dst_dir, pattern='*'):
    """Iterate through src_dir, processing all files that match pattern and
    store them, including their parent directories in dst_dir.
    """
    assert src_dir != dst_dir, 'Source and destination dir must differ.'
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(src_dir):
        # Filter out files that match pattern only.
        filenames = filter(lambda fname: fnmatch(fname, pattern), filenames)

        if filenames:
            dir_ = os.path.join(dst_dir, dirpath)
            os.makedirs(dir_)
            for fname in filenames:
                in_fname = os.path.join(dirpath, fname)
                out_fname = os.path.join(dir_, fname)

                # At this point, the destination directory is created and you
                # have a valid input / output filename, so you'd call your
                # function to process these files.  I just copy them :D
                shutil.copyfile(in_fname, out_fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], '*.txt')
```

Comment: Agreed, `os.walk` is probably the key to what he needs.